# WordPress list pages alternating with thumbnails

Tags: php, wordpress

On my front page, I want to display pages but with alternate thumbnail sizes. I have 2 thumbnail sizes which should be used.
Page 1: Size A
Page 2: Size B
Page 3: Size A
Page 4: Size A
Page 5: Size A
Page 6: Size B
Page 7: Size A
then start over again with the order.

At the moment, I got the following code, which I want to reuse on other pages of the site to display child pages:

```
<?php query_posts('post_type=page&order=ASC&post_parent=0');
while(have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
   <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">
        <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
        <?php the_title(); ?>
   </a>
<?php endwhile;?>
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how you decide, which approach to pick. Regarding the order of your pattern, it would make sense, to do it via `css`. Wordpress also outputs altering classes like `even` and `odd` but, since you have Three following (A A A) this is not the right approach. I think easiest is if you use CSS and make us of nth-of-type(int):

```
/* First Post Type A */
.your-post-type:first-child {

}
/* Second Post Type B*/
.your-post-type:nth-of-type(2) {

}
/* Third Post Type A */
.your-post-type:nth-of-type(3) {

}
/* Fourth Post Type A */
.your-post-type:nth-of-type(4) {

}
/* Fifth Post Type A */
.your-post-type:nth-of-type(5) {

}
/* Sixth Post Type B */
.your-post-type:nth-of-type(6) {

}
/* Seventh Post Type A */
.your-post-type:nth-of-type(7) {

}
```

If your custom query on the frontpage is not limited to 7, well then you have extend this example up to 14 or how many posts you have and want to show. Limit your query with the last argument `shotposts=X`:

```
<?php query_posts('post_type=page&order=ASC&post_parent=0&showposts=14')..
```

Comment: Great hint. I made it with css and put the thumb as a background image.

Comment: This is a terrible solution... For `n` posts you'll have `n` CSS entries? Just to define two different styles? I'd be much better to just define `.size-A` and `.size-B` and apply them to every corresponding post in PHP.

Comment: Thanks for calling it terrible - I did assume, that he is not capable/willing to dig deeper into WordPress / PHP. Ever thought of that?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you already defined your thumbnail sizes (e.g. using `add_image_size()`) and given that your sequence `A B A A A B A` seems quite random to me, I'd repeatedly iterate an array with the thumb-sizes to pass them to `the_post_thumbnail()` function. Something like:

```
<?php
query_posts('post_type=page&order=ASC&post_parent=0');
$thumbsizes = [
    'size-a',
    'size-b',
    'size-a',
    'size-a',
    'size-a',
    'size-b',
    'size-a',
];
$i = 0;
while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
   <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">
        <?php the_post_thumbnail($thumbsizes[ $i ]); ?>
        <?php the_title(); ?>
   </a>
<?php
$i = ($i + 1) % count($thumbsizes);
endwhile;
?>
```

*Of course, your CSS has something to say on thumbnail sizes too...*